# Remove Project explorer from rdditor

Tags: java, eclipse

Can please someone tell me how to remove the project explorer from the editor? It is really annoying. I tried to reset the perspective but didn't help.
Thank you very much in advance

[image]

Comment: This is the 'breadcrumb' toolbar

Comment: Ok, sorry for the duplicate question, i didn't knew the toolbar's name, thank you.